# Efficient lookup in a range table

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby

I have a table of 1.6M IP ranges with organization names. 
The IP addresses are converted to integers. The table is in the form of:

[image]

I have a list of 2000 unique ip addresses (e.g. 321223, 531223, ....) that need to be translated to an organization name.

I loaded the translation table as a mysql table with an index on **IP_from** and **IP_to**. I looped through the 2000 IP addresses, running one query per ip address, and after 15 minutes the report was still running. 
The query I'm using is

```
select organization from iptable where ip_addr BETWEEN ip_start AND ip_end
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this batch look-up? I'll use my fingers if it's a good solution. And in case someone has a Ruby-specific solution, I want to mention that I'm using Ruby.

Comment: You want to create an R-Tree (spatial) index over `(IP_from, IP_to)`.

Comment: what indices have you used?

Comment: We need a lot more information, like schemas and the queries. We also need to know why Ruby and Rails are tags.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given that you already have an index on `ip_start`, this is how to use it best, assuming that you want to make one access per IP (`1234` in this example):

```
select organization from (
    select ip_end, organization
    from iptable
    where ip_start <= 1234
    order by ip_start desc
    limit 1
) subqry where 1234 <= ip_end
```

This will use your index to start a scan which stops immediately because of the `limit 1`. The cost should only be marginally higher than the one of a simple indexed access. Of course, this technique relies on the fact that the ranges defined by `ip_start` and `ip_end` never overlap.

The problem with your original approach is that mysql, being unaware of this constraint, can only use the index to determine where to start or stop the scan that (it thinks) it needs in order to find all matches for your query.

Comment: You sir, are a mysql(sql) god. Using the index and my query from my original question, I found that 1) IP addresses that were 9 digits or less (e.g.248082010) took ~40ms.  2) IP addresss that were above a billion, i.e. 10 digits (like 1823194021), took about 600ms and that's what was killing performance.  Using your query, everything takes .5ms. Wow.

Comment: Thank you @gitb, but if I were a god, the world would be a pantheon ;-) Do you mind if I change the title of your question to "Efficient lookup in a range table"? (or maybe you have a better title). That would be in the direction of an "efficient lookup in Stack Overflow"

Answer (score -1):

Possibly the most efficient way of doing a lookup of this kind is loading the list of addresses you want to look up into a temporary table in the database and finding the intersection with an SQL join, rather than checking each address with a separate SQL statement.

In any case you'll need to have an index on (IP_from, IP_to).

Comment: Quite likely, none of my 2000 IP addresses will be in the lookup table. They will fall between the **from** and **to** fields. So I don't see how I can do a join.

Comment: You can write `JOIN ON ip >= ip_from AND ip <= ip_to` Might not be as efficient as a join with `=` but with proper indexes it's not a lot worse.

Comment: @Joni, what "proper indices" can inform mysql that only one record can match the condition for a given `ip`?

Comment: You'll get all matches, @Walter. If there are no overlapping ranges you'll get at most one result for each IP though.

Comment: @Joni, my understanding is that, on a given table, you can only use one index at a time, and that a multiple index on `(ip_from, ip_to)` can only be used to find all `ip >= ip_from`, so that a scan is needed to check that `ip <= ip_to`. Or is there a way to do better than that (apart from my solution?) Mine is a true question, not a rhetorical one.

Comment: @WalterTross, you're right, I've done a little reading and my understanding of database indexing was incomplete. A regular B-tree index on (ip_from, ip_to) will only help with the condition on ip_from just like you say and the simple query I suggest will imply the database has to scan through thousands of entries to satisfy the condition on ip_to.

Comment: @Joni, well, I've learned something too: in particular cases more than one index can be used (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index-merge-optimization.html), although this does not apply to the case at hand.