# Return count of database rows that have sequential values in column from left join

Tags: mysql, count, left-join

I have 2 tables.
`availabilities` and `time_slots`.  The `availabilities` table has a `time_slot_id` column.  `time_slots` simply holds all the times of a 24 hour day in 15 minute intervals.  It has `from`, `to`, and `sequence` columns. With data in it, it looks like this.

`|from      |to        |sequence
|00:00:00  |00:15:00  |0
|00:15:00  |00:30:00  |1
|00:30:00  |00:45:00  |2
|00:45:00  |01:00:00  |3`

and so one all the way to midnight again with the sequence incrementing by 1.  I need to get out availabilities where its time slot is sequential with the one adjacent to it either side, and then count the number of sequential availabilities.  So far I have this query below which gets me out all the availabilities that has sequential time slots, but can't work out how to count them.

```
SELECT a1.date, ts1.sequence, ts1.from, ts1.to
FROM availabilities a1
LEFT JOIN time_slots ts1 ON a1.time_slot_id = ts1.id
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
            FROM availabilities a2
            LEFT JOIN time_slots ts2 ON a2.time_slot_id = ts2.id
            WHERE ts1.sequence IN (ts2.sequence - 1, ts2.sequence + 1)
            )
```

It is entirely possible that there may be many sets of sequential availabilities so need to just ensure that at least one of the sets of sequential availabilities is greater than a certain count (3 for example) which could be different every time.  That variable number will depend on some user import but I just need to know how to make sure I have enough availabilities to cover that count.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can try something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49613118/mysql-query-to-find-available-car-for-booking-between-date-range-with-continuous/49615489#49615489

Comment: Could you please add SqlFiddle ?